# Hibernate 4.3.0.Final and Illegal attempt to set lock mode on a non-SELECT query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I just upgraded from 4.2.8 to 4.3.0 and I am not getting the exception "Illegal attempt to set lock mode on a non-SELECT query". The query is a simple @NamedQuery that performs an update operation. Any ideas where I should look to find out why this WAS working in 4.2.8 but not in 4.3.0?

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly the same problem for me. Have you sorted this out? It seems that the fix isn't coming with the next hibernate release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was caused by [this change](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8563). Someone has reported an issue similar to yours in [this bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8756) and submitted a pull request that is still pending.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the 4.3.0.Final driver. There are only one solution I have been able to find. Since 4.3.0 supports named parameters in NamedNativeQueries (as well as collection named parameters for in clauses) you can simply rewrite these queries as Native Queries. Then it will work.

The scary thing to me of course is that in the Hibernate EntityManager unit tests, they must have NOT ONE unit test that performs update queries in a NamedQuery. How can this be? I have no idea. I haven't looked at the code to see what their test coverage is like. But just one would have shown the regression.